# client_side_validations and devise error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

Im validating a form with client side validations and I also have devise, 
this is in my form:

```
    <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :current_password, "Old password:", :class => "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :password, "New password:", :class => "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.password_field :password  %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "New password, again:", :class => "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation  %> 
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

and I have this in my model

> validates_presence_of :password, :message => 'required'
>
> validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :message => 'required'
>
> validates_presence_of :current_password, :message => 'required'

In the end my view shows something like this 
[image]

Why are the messages different?
I would like to have all my messages to be consistent. 
How do I change the default message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `config/locales/en.yml` file, like so:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            current_password:
              blank: "Required"
```

Note that you need to replace `user` with the actual name of your model.